# Why isnt my gsap working even if I have downloaded the file?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, gsap

I was creating a website and the gsap doesnt work, I have downloaded gsap.min.js and used this code on my main js

```
gsap.from('.home__img', {opacity: 0, duration: 2, delay:.5, x:60 })
gsap.from($box, '.home__data', {opacity: 0, duration: 2, delay:.8, y:25 })
gsap.from($box, '.home__greeting, .home__name, .home__profession, .home__button', {opacity: 0, duration: 2, delay:1, y:25, ease:'expo.out',stagger:.2 })
```

What went wrong here? and how do I fix it? note that I also added

```
  <script src="assets/js/gsap.min.js"></script>
```

to the index.html

Comment: Are you including the GSAP library _before_ your main javascript file?

Comment: @Sean no im not, im including it after ive written all the other code, like at the end

Comment: That would explain your issue. If you aren't using `async` and `defer`, the site will load the scripts in order, and the `gsap.min.js` script is what defines your `gsap` global object, so you need it before your script.